# AVCaptureVideoDataOutput stops delivering frames in iOS 14

Tags: ios, avfoundation, opengl-es-2.0, metal

I have the following setup:

- An `AVCaptureSession` with a `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` delivers video frames from the camera.
- OpenGL textures are created from the `CVPixelBuffers` using a `CVOpenGLESTextureCache`.
- Some OpenGL-based image processing is performed on the frames (with many intermediate steps) in a separate queue.
- The final texture of the processing pipeline is rendered into a `CAEAGLLayer` on the main thread (with proper context and share group handling).

This worked very well up to iOS 13. Now in iOS 14 the `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` suddenly stops delivering new frames (to the delegate) after ~4 sec. of capture—without any warning or log message.

Some observations:

- The `AVCaptureSession` is still running (`isRunning` is `true`, `isInterrupted` is `false`).
- All connections between the camera device and output are still there and active.
- The capture indicator (green circle in the status bar, new in iOS 14) is still there.
- The output's delegate does not report any frame drops.
- When I perform an action that causes the session to be re-configured (like switching to the front camera), the output will start delivering frames again for ~4 sec. and then stop again.
- When I don't process and display the frames, the output continues to deliver frames without interruption.

I'm debugging this for a while now and I'm pretty clueless. Any hints or ideas on what might cause this behavior now in iOS 14 are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

I'm getting the attachments (metadata) of the incoming sample buffers and accidentally leaked the dictionary due to wrong bridging.

So instead of this

```
NSDictionary* attachments = (__bridge NSDictionary* _Nullable)CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(NULL, sampleBuffer, kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate);
```

I should have done this

```
NSDictionary* attachments = (__bridge_transfer NSDictionary* _Nullable)CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(NULL, sampleBuffer, kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate);
```

Interestingly, this leak caused the capture session to stop delivering new sample buffers after 126 frames—without any warning, error, or notification.

Comment: Hi Frank, I'm facing the same issue, but I don't need to get metadata in my case, is there any experience to detect what is the root problem here? Thanks in advanced

Comment: Hmm, difficult. The main reason was that the sample buffers were still referenced somehow by the metadata dictionary and so did not return to the pool. You should check if there are way too many sample buffers at runtime (with the memory graph, for instance) and maybe you can find out, what's retaining them.

Comment: Thanks Frank. I found the problem which due to memory leak in CoreML. Somehow the buffers are held by CoreML and never released =(